# Express Range error after login app

Tags: node.js, spring, express, tomcat

I have a node express app as frontend and a spring/tomcat app running as backend. I tested backend api and everything works fine, in browser when I put an api request it shows the json response. Although when I launch frontend app in node and enter credentials in login form in browser (localhost:3000), after form login it gives the following error:

```
 Express
    500 RangeError: port should be >= 0 and < 65536: 8080;

       at lookupAndConnect (net.js:945:13)
       at Socket.connect (net.js:922:5)
       at Agent.exports.connect.exports.createConnection (net.js:68:35)
       at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:188:16)
       at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:157:23)
       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:142:16)
       at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
       at Object.wrappedRequest (/home/yanet/Documentos/remax-fe-master-f73335bb25073887ba387954032ee534ad955002/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/core/http.js:124:31)
       at /home/yanet/Documentos/remax-fe-master-f73335bb25073887ba387954032ee534ad955002/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer.js:148:22
       at ErrorTracer.monitor (/home/yanet/Documentos/remax-fe-master-f73335bb25073887ba387954032ee534ad955002/node_modules/newrelic/lib/error.js:146:12)
```

My app.js seems to be fine. When app launches it shows the message:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
```

This is part of app.js, I omitted the part that has to do with routing: app.get and app.post.

```
var express = require('express')
    , routes = require('./routes')
    , http = require('http')
    , path = require('path')
    , url = require('url')
    , passport = require('passport')
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
    , ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn
    , bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
    , util = require('util')
    , expressValidator = require('express-validator')
    , newrelic = require('newrelic')
// Modules Remax
    , catalog = require('./routes/catalog')
    , login = require('./routes/login')
    , user = require('./routes/user')
    , rrhh = require('./routes/rrhh')
    , stock = require('./routes/stock')
    , movements = require('./routes/movements')
    , ctasctes = require('./routes/ctasctes')
    , ranking = require('./routes/ranking')
    , stats = require('./routes/stats')
    , statsResumenAgentes = require('./routes/stats.resumen.agentes')
    , statsResumenOficinas = require('./routes/stats.resumen.oficinas')
    , reports = require('./routes/reports')
    , rendicion = require('./routes/rendicion')
    , configuration = require('./routes/configuration')
    , admin = require('./routes/admin')
    , accessControl = require('./routes/accessControl')
    , ilist = require('./routes/ilist')
    , benchmark = require('./routes/benchmark')    
// Redis
    , RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express)
    , redis = require("redis")
    , redisClient
// App
    , app = express()
    , flash = require('connect-flash');

/**
 * Redis configuration
 */
if (process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
    redisClient = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {no_ready_check: true});
    redisClient.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1]);
} else {
    redisClient = redis.createClient();
}

/**
 * Session destroy
 */
process.on('exit', function () {
    user.destroy();
});

/**
 * Error handling
 */
process.on("uncaughtException", function (err) {
    console.log("Error in application: " + err.message);
    console.log(err.stack);
    console.log("---------------------------------------");
});

/**
 * Init user condifguration
 */
user.init();

/**
 * App configuration
 */
app.configure(function () {
    app.locals({
        listaModulosSidebar: accessControl.listaModulosSidebar(),
        canViewURL: accessControl.canView
    });
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    //app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(expressValidator);
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: "somekey",
        maxAge: new Date() + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000, //2hs
        store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient, ttl: 2 * 60 * 60})
    }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(accessControl.validate);
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.locals.loggedUser = req.user;
        var i = req.path.indexOf('/', 1);
        if(i > 1){
            res.locals.modulepath = req.path.substring(0, i);
        } else {
            res.locals.modulepath = req.path;
        }
        next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

process.setMaxListeners(0);

/**
 * Session
 */
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, function (username, password, done) {
    user.login(username, password, function(err, user, message){
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: message
            });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

/**
 * Create server
 */
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that start the server?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the definition of my Environment Variable in /etc/environment , which had the PORT, it was a misspell with a comma.
I had

`REMAX_SERVICE_HOST=localhost:8080;`

And I fixed to:

`REMAX_SERVICE_HOST=localhost:8080`